# SQL query to get records even if count is 0 in one table

Tags: sql

```
select id, name, 'First Category' as category, count(id) as totalCalls
from missed_call
where name = 'whatever1'
group by name, category
UNION
select id, name, 'Second Category' as category, count(id) as totalCalls
from missed_call
where name = 'whatever2'
group by name, category
order by name ASC, totalCalls DESC
```

The previous query will not retrieve the records where *totalCalls* is 0.

So, how can I do to get those records and present *totalCalls* as 0?

**UPDATE**: I have tried changing `count(id) as totalCalls` for `IFNULL(count(id), 0) as totalCalls` but it doesn't solve the problem. Perhaps, because count(id) is actually not null, it just does not exist.

Comment: Your question is not specific. My assumption: you can consider using GROUP BY if you are counting the numbers of totalcalls based on categories.

Comment: What are you expecting to see?  If there are no records in the table, there's nothing to show-- unless you have another table somewhere that lists all the categories.

Comment: @dbaseman that's what I was afraid of. The thing is that "categories" are not in the database. They are defined in the query when certain conditions exist. Otherwise I would do the outer join to get those records. Is that my only alternative to this problem? Regards

Comment: I agree with @dbaseman. I've added an answer to address the problem of defining cateogries in a separate table. All the other answer will not work if there are no records in the databse and you still want to report them. Without the `category` table any hack you come up with may lead to further isssue later on when you wan to write more queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are unwilling to expand your database schema you can always pretend there is a table:

```
select surrogateTable.name, 
       surrogateTable.Category, 
       count(id) as totalCalls
from 
(
  select 'whatever1' Name,
         'First Category' Category
  union all
  select 'whatever2',
         'Second Category'
) surrogateTable
left join missed_call
  on surrogateTable.Name = missed_call.Name
group by surrogateTable.name, surrogateTable.category
```

I dropped id in select because you should not select something you are not grouping on - this is probably MySql.

[Check this on Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19a20/3).

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you only look at missed calls and not at categories, so you cannot notice categories that have no corresponding missed calls.

Here is the skeleton that will do that, supposing you will adapt it to the real structure of the category table.

```
SELECT ...
FROM Category cat
    LEFT JOIN missed_call call ON call.category = category.id
WHERE (call.name = 'whatever1' OR call.category IS NULL)
GROUP BY call.name, call.category
...
```

Note especially `call.category IS NULL`.  The column is supposedly not nullable; so this really checks for a `Category` row without any corresponding calls, an artifact of the outer join.

Comment: This is the way to go. If there is no categories table, create one (either temporary or on the fly, with `(SELECT 'whatever1' AS name UNION SELECT 'whatever2') AS cat`

Comment: Yes this would work but you are then hard coding your category names into your query. Not ideal from a maintenance point of view.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a table named `category` to contain a complete list of all category names that are possible, even those that have no calls assigned to them (i.e. zero).

```
create table category
(
    id  numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
    name    varchar(10) NULL
)
```

Then you can query the full list of categories from this table and LEFT JOIN the results against what you have from above.

You can then amend your `missed_call` to use foreign keys against your new `category` table for better efficiency and better schema design

```
create table missed_call
(
    id  numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
    first_category_id numeric(10,0) NULL,
    second_category_id numeric(10,0) NULL,
    name  varchar(12)
)
```